# How to update document in mongodb NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am using this command to update the document.

```
order = await db.collection("orders").findOneAndUpdate({ order_id: req.body.ORDERID }, {$set: { payment_status: "Paid", paymentInfo: JSON.stringify(myrequest) }})

console.log(order)
```

But the document is not updated instead return this in console

```
lastErrorObject: { n: 0, updatedExisting: false },
  value: null,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1663565745, i: 13 }),
    signature: {
      hash: new Binary(Buffer.from("5165sd1vdsvds651vds5vvs5dvdsvdskvjdsv, "hex"), 0),
      keyId: new Long("1451151132154123165")
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about req.body.ORDERID value?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

To update the Document Using MongoDB two conditions are  required filter and update information.

```
 const myquery = { orderId: req.body.ORDER_ID };
const newvalues = { $set: { payment_status: "Paid", paymentInfo: JSON.stringify('your Payment Info in JSON format') }};
  await db.collection("orders").updateOne(myquery, newvalues);
```

Please go through the [Document](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_update.asp) for detailed Information

Comment: I am also doing the same thing.

Comment: I found the error. Actually, req.body.ORDER_ID is returning a string. I have to parse it to an integer first.